# #! /bin/bash or #! /usr/bin/env bash?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to write some provisioning shell scripts for Vagrant dev environment. I'm used to start bash scripts as follows

```
#! /bin/bash
```

But after surfing through some git repos I found out that in most cases guys use

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

So the question is: what the difference and what is the most decent way to start a bash script? (any alternatives are also appreciated)

Comment: On the portability front, `/bin/bash` will not exist on a stock BSD system, as for example on OpenBSD, if bash is actually installed, it will be under `/usr/local/bin`, unless the admin has taken additional steps to symlink it to other locations.

Comment: @thrig, on the portability front, there's no guarantee that env will be `/usr/bin/env` any more than there's a guarantee that `bash` will be `/bin/bash`.  Misusing `env` on the shebang line like this doesn't fix the problem, it just shifts it from `bash` to `env`.

Comment: @cas, so what is your point of view?